# Mac OSX boot option missing after Bootcamp and Installation of Windows 8.1 and BitLocker

Tags: windows, macos, windows-8.1, boot-camp, bitlocker

A user has the most recent MacBook Pro, we've installed Mac OS X, and then Boot Camp and Windows 8.1 Professional, and enabled BitLocker (which obviously re-arranged the Windows partitions). We are no longer given the option to boot the Mac OSX Partition. Is there any way we can get it back?

*Update:* I think it had something to do with this http://anand-iyer.com/blog/2014/fixing-missing-bootcamp-partition-in-osx.html

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me on Windows 10.  In my case the enable bitlocker process changed the type code on my OSX partition.  To verify and fix on windows, use gdisk.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/

## Verification

- Open Administrative Command Prompt and run gdisk64.exe (assuming x64).
- "0:" which is a special syntax to describe disks in windows. (I only have one harddrive and 0: is the first)
- "p" to print the partition table

```
Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: 0:
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Command (? for help): p
Disk 0:: 977105060 sectors, 465.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): FDABFC64-BD61-4C2D-95CC-AB54D6A16DAA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 977105026
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4028 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       293378375   139.7 GiB   0700  Customer
   3       293378376       294647911   619.9 MiB   AF00  Recovery HD
   4       294649856       976392292   325.1 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       976394240       977104895   347.0 MiB   2700
```

In my case partition #2 is my OSX installation.  Note that Code is 0700 which is incorrect (gdisk describes 0700 as "Microsoft basic data").  If you see the same thing proceed with the fix, if not stop here.  Also, double check that your MBR is protective and not hybrid.

## The Fix

```
Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-5): 2
Current type is 'Apple HFS/HFS+'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 700): AF00
Changed type of partition to 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 4028 free sectors (2.0 MiB) available in 4
segments, the largest of which is 1947 (973.5 KiB) in size.

Command (? for help): w
```

- "t" is the command to change a partition's type code
- "2" is my OSX partition index (use yours)
- "AF00" is the type code for Apple HFS/HFS+
- "v" verifies the disk
- "w" writes the table to disk and exits

Answer (score 0):

The solution "almost" worked for me, except that newer Macs are using a different filesystem type, namely `AF0A`:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1               6           76805   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2           76806        48416767   184.4 GiB   AF0A
   3        48416768        69264918   79.5 GiB    0700
   4        69265152        69388031   480.0 MiB   2700
   5        69388288       122138111   201.2 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
```

After modifying my MacOS partition type from whatever type Bitlocker had set it to (I think it was `2700`, not `0700`), I am able to boot into MacOS again, both by holding the Option key during startup and also from Bootcamp Control Panel on Windows.