# Windows10 - Bootcamp Could not locate the macOS boot volume - mac partition unknown

Tags: windows-10, boot, mac, partitioning, boot-camp

In my Macbook pro (2016 touch bar), previously I installed Windows 10 and upgraded to creators version. In Windows session, in the bootcamp "Restart in macOS..." option is returning "Could not locate the macOS boot volume." error.

When I ran the gdisk tool (based on [this thread answer](https://superuser.com/questions/848793/mac-osx-boot-option-missing-after-bootcamp-and-installation-of-windows-8-1-and-b)) to list the partition details, I see my mac partition (#2) has FFFF code (seems to be unknown)

```
c:\Temp>gdisk64.exe
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: 0:
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk 0:: 122138133 sectors, 465.9 GiB
Sector size (logical): 4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 67089514-C692-4DF1-8679-633BDE4D77E6
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 122138127
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2112456 sectors (8.1 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1               6           76805   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2           76806        58758145   223.9 GiB   FFFF  NoName
   3        60870144       121919301   232.9 GiB   0700  BOOTCAMP
   4       121919488       122137855   853.0 MiB   2700
```

Any help to boot into macOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still boot the macOS partition right? You can hold down Alt/Option upon startup and it will give you a list of bootable volumes. Choose Macintosh HD (or your macOS partition) to boot it. Once you're done, you may wish to change the default boot to macOS in System Preferences -> Startup Disk. To boot your Windows partition again, hold Alt/Option upon startup and choose BOOTCAMP (your Windows partition).

If you have any other Bootcamp questions, let me know. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple, you are not suppose to use the APFS with the Boot Camp Assistant application. However, if you do so, then the following will fix the problem you are having.

Since the Windows Boot Camp software can detect bootable "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" volumes, the follow instructions create such a volume. Instead of placing macOS in the volume, a third party boot manager, called rEFInd, will be substituted. This boot manager will then be configured to silently boot the macOS stored in the APFS container. Finally, macOS will be instructed to not automatically mount this new volume at startup.

Below are the steps. The commands need to be entered into a Terminal application window.

> Note: You will have to replace "Macintosh HD" with the the name of your macOS volume.

1. Create the new volume.  The `diskutil` command, shown below, shrinks the APFS container by 300 MB and creates the new 200 MB "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" volume labeled "Macintosh HD via rEFInd".

   ```
   sudo diskutil ap resizeContainer disk1 223600M JHFS+ "Macintosh HD via rEFInd" 200M
   ```

   After the command completes, restart the Mac.
2. Download the rEFInd Boot Manager software from this [SourceForge web site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). Enter the following commands to install the software to the "Macintosh HD via rEFInd" volume.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.2
   ./refind-install --ownhfs /dev/disk0s3
   ```

   > Note: The error message `Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc` was expected and can be ignored.
3. Configure the TextEdit application. Open TextEdit, then navigate to the "Preferences..." window. Uncheck all the "Options", as shown below. When finished, quit TextEdit.

   [image: y1]
4. Use the command below to navigate to the folder containing the `refind.conf` file.

   ```
   cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD via rEFInd/System/Library/CoreServices"
   ```

   Make a backup copy of this file.

   ```
   sudo cp refind.conf refind.conf.orignal
   ```

   Add write permissions to the `CoreServices` folder and the `refind.conf` file.

   ```
   sudo chmod a+w . refind.conf
   ```

   Open the file in the TextEdit application.

   ```
   open -e refind.conf
   ```
5. Add the following lines to the end of the `refind.conf` file. You should be able to just cut and paste these lines. When finished, save the changes, then quit TextEdit.

   ```
   #
   # Added to make rEFInd silent. 
   #
   menuentry "Macintosh HD via rEFInd" {
       icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_mac.png
       volume "Macintosh HD"
       loader \System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
       ostype MacOS
       graphics on
   }
   timeout -1
   hideui all
   scanfor manual
   ```
6. Enter the following commands to modify the `/etc/fstab` file. This entry will instruct macOS not to mount the volume labeled "Macintosh HD via rEFInd" at startup.

   > Note: The character sequence `\040` is just the octal representation of the space character.

   ```
   sudo bash 
   echo >>/etc/fstab
   echo "LABEL=Macintosh\040HD\040via\040rEFInd none hfs rw,noauto" >>/etc/fstab    
   exit
   ```

   > Note: The correct way, to edit the `/etc/fstab` file, is to use the command `sudo vifs`. Using the `echo` command is just a quick shortcut.

   When finished, restart the Mac.

Now when choosing Boot Camp from the Control Panel, you should get something similar to what is shown below.

[image: capture1]

Answer (score 1):

This is because of High Sierra's new APFS (Apple File System) on Apple PCIe-based solid state drives, as well as 2.5" solid state drives on older Macs such as a 2012, like the one I have.

Windows 10 Boot Camp control panel doesn't recognize that file system yet, so you have to reboot and hold down the Option key to toggle which one you want to boot into.

If you set your Mac as the startup disk on the Mac side of things and simply reboot Windows, it will always boot back into Mac OS.  Then if you want to go to Windows, just reboot the Mac Parson and hold the option key down and select Windows to get back into Windows.

When you're done in Windows, you won't have to hold the option key again since you've already selected Mac as the default startup disk on the Mac, and so just say Start Menu->Power->Restart, and it will boot into Mac automatically.