# Restore the Bootcamp application on windows 8.1

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, boot-camp

I have recently installed a windows 8.1 on my iMac through bootcamp, and it was very, VERY buggy. So I bought a new one and installed it on top of the windows 8.1 and now I lost the bootcamp "300 GB" allocated for my Mac and I cannot get back to using the MacOS.

Is there a way I can download the Bootcamp as a software and just get back to the mac or is it lost, and if so is there a way to recover?

P.S: I am really panicking because there are very important files on my Mac.

Comment: You bought a new one what? Windows? How did you attempt to install it? To remove a bootcamp installation you must remove it using the Boot Camp Assistant, otherwise you'll break things. Start from Recovery [Cmd/R at the chimes], open terminal & run `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list` then post the results to your question.

Comment: I bought a new Windows, and I have successfully installed it through the old Windows, I just realized that my mistake was that I didn't go back to the MacOS and install it through there, so now, I have lost the Bootcamp application from windows and now I am stuck and can't go back to the MacOS..

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac. Sometimes you can just download the BootCamp Support Software directly to Windows.

Comment: I can't check from here, but it's iMac w/Retina display 21.5" and the model is 2016

Comment: If you restart you Mac and hold down the option key, then you will get the Startup Manager. From there, you should be able to boot to macOS. Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

When starting or restarting your Mac, you can reach the Startup Manager by immediately holding down the option key. To boot to a volume, first select an icon. Next, select the arrow below the icon. If you hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key when selecting the arrow, then the selected volume will become the default startup volume.

The Boot Camp Support Software for your Mac can be download by opening the Boot Camp Assistant. Select "Action" from the menu bar, then select "Download Windows Support Software". You will need to copy the software to a FAT formatted flash drive. Under Windows, run the setup application in the "BootCamp" folder.

Windows 10 is a far superior operating system compared to Widows 8.1. In case you did not know, you can still upgrade to Windows 10 for free. See the article [Here's how to get Windows 10 for free -- until Dec. 31](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/microsoft-windows-10-free-upgrade-offer-assistive-features/).

If your a using the new APFS to contain your macOS volume, then you may not be able to restart to macOS directly from the Windows control panel. There is a workaround for this. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1267775/windows10-bootcamp-could-not-locate-the-macos-boot-volume-mac-partition-unkn/1277245#1277245).

If you upgrade to Windows 10 and your system still seems buggy, you may want to consider a clean install of Windows 10. This is best done by using a 16 GB or larger flash drive. If interested, let me know and I will include the instructions.